# Use SELinux to restrict a directory to a particular user

Tags: command-line, permissions, selinux

I have a couple of questions: (Sysadmins tasks)

Here is what I asked to do

> Create user Tim and add him to the supplementary group Webdev (Create
>   the group if it doesn't exist), also Set Tim's default home directory
>   to /websites - if this directory does not exist, create it.

So here is what I did:

```
useradd -m -d /websites Tim 
groupadd Webdev
useradd -aG Webdev Tim
```

I think I did that correctly.

Now for the second task, I am really confused

> Apply the same SELinux contexts and permissions to /websites that
>   would be found on a user's /home directory such that Tim and only Tim
>   will have access to /websites

How would I be able to do that ? I mean should the Tim's home directory be  /websites anyways ?

Answer (score 2):

First question: Yes.  Although you could have used the `-G` option to add the supplementary group `Webdev` at account creation time: `-G Webdev`.

SELinux marks users' home directories as `user_home_dir_t`. Therefore to set the SELinux context you can use:

```
# chcon -t user_home_dir_t /websites
```

Note that if you had another user's home directory as reference, you could also copy it with `# chcon --reference=<other home> /website`

To set owner (Tim):

```
# chown Tim: /website
```

The colon (`:`) after the username tells `chown` to set the group ownership to be the same. That is, `ls -ld /website` will show `Tim Tim`.

To set permissions:

```
# chmod 755 /website
```

`755` is the default for home directories on most (all?) systems and translates to `rwxr-xr-x`.